# Uma linguagem de programação específica para jogos

Tags: característica-linguagem, jogos, design-de-linguagem

Existe alguma linguagem de programação **específica** para desenvolvimento de jogos eletrônicos? Uma linguagem que seja otimizada de alto desempenho para usar instruções de processamento de mídia, que seja vinculada à **GPU**?

Eu sei que muitos vão dizer que quando se fala em jogos se fala em **C++**, mas essa é uma linguagem de propósito geral, eu queria saber se existe algo realmente específico para área de games e mídia em geral. Não quero saber a respeito de bibliotecas gráficas nem nada do tipo, eu quero saber de uma **linguagem**.

Existe alguma pesquisa científica nessa área? Algum projeto em desenvolvimento, ou até mesmo um protótipo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Existe alguma linguagem de programação específica para desenvolvimento
>   de jogos eletrônicos?

Não. Simplesmente porque não há requisitos únicos ou especiais ao se desenvolver jogos que requereriam uma linguagem de programação específica. De fato, a sua pergunta poderia ser refeita para qualquer domínio de problema e a resposta *provavelmente* continuaria sendo "não". Por exemplo:

- existe linguagem de programação específica para desenvolver sistemas de supermercado?
- existe linguagem de programação específica para desenvolver tags rastreadoras de gado?

Dependendo do domínio do problema pode ocorrer de existir uma linguagem específica porque ela é *proprietária*, isto é, criada pelo fabricante de um certo equipamento de hardware e, portanto, necessária para uso nesse equipamento. Mas eu diria que isso é raro de ocorrer porque:

1. os fabricantes não desejam ter esse esforço (de tempo e dinheiro)
2. os fabricantes desejam que os fornecedores e clientes interessados em usar seus equipamentos o façam com facilidade

É por isso que é comum, mesmo em domínios de problema envolvendo hardwares específicos, que se use linguagens portáveis e já conhecidas como C, C++ e até mesmo Assembly, com a provisão de no máximo um SDK (Software Development Kit) específico para a plataforma.

No caso de jogos, os consoles (PlayStation, XBox, Nintendo, ...) são os equipamentos e por isso é bem comum que o desenvolvimento de sistemas (os jogos!) para eles seja executado em C++ ou Java com o auxílio de SDKs dos fabricantes.

> Uma linguagem que seja otimizada de alto desempenho para usar
>   instruções de processamento de mídia, que seja vinculada à GPU?

Depende do que você quer dizer com "otimização de alto desempenho". Se a linguagem for compilada (caso de Assembly, C, C++, por exemplo) ou utilizar recursos de compilação dinâmica (como o [Just-In-Time](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIT) no Java, por exemplo), seu desempenho vai ser o melhor possível na máquina *considerando as soluções implementadas pelo programador*.

O uso de GPU não *necessariamente* depende da linguagem. DirectX e OpenGL fazem justamente essa ponte em se tratando da manipulação e renderização de gráficos. Eu digo "não necessariamente" porque há "linguagens" (vamos chamar assim) voltadas ao uso da GPU para a [computação paralela](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_paralela), e que, portanto, *não tem nada a ver com um domínio de problema específico*.

[Cuda](http://www.nvidia.com.br/object/cuda_home_new_br.html), por exemplo, é a "linguagem" (que na verdade está mais para uma plataforma desenvolvida em cima do C/C++) da NVIDIA para a solução de problemas com natureza intrinsecamente paralela (por exemplo, a soma de dois vetores, cujos itens podem ser somados em kernels concorrentes) com altíssimo desempenho. Ela explora a GPU para realizar esse processamento de forma concorrente e a linguagem é construída de forma a abstrair do programador o parelelismo e a consolidação dos resultados ([exemplos aqui](https://eradsp2010.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/curso2_cuda_camargo.pdf)). Ela pode ser usada em jogos? Claro! Não somente para a renderização de elementos gráficos, mas também para a Inteligência Artificial e qualquer outro problema que se beneficie de paralelismo. Mas veja como não é algo específico para esse domínio de problema.

> Eu sei que muitos vão dizer que quando se fala em jogos se fala em
>   C++, mas essa é uma linguagem de propósito geral, eu queria saber se
>   existe algo realmente específico para área de games e mídia em geral.
>   Não quero saber a respeito de bibliotecas gráficas nem nada do tipo,
>   eu quero saber de uma linguagem.

C++ é muito utilizada porque é muito conhecida e porque é bastante difundida em diversas plataformas de hardware. Há inúmeras outras que podem ser utilizadas. Java é bem comum também. Python, como mencionaram em comentários, está se tornando cada vez mais comum. Só que, como eu respondi antes, nenhuma delas é específica para jogos e dificilmente vai haver uma porque não há necessidade.

Você diz que não tem interesse em saber de bibliotecas gráficas nem "nada do tipo". Mas aí está justamente o cerne da questão: **o que os jogos realmente se diferenciam de outros problemas é nas suas necessidades**. E eu não estou falando apenas de gráficos. A física é uma importante necessidade de muitos jogos, envolvendo a detecção de colisões (quando um objeto "toca" outro) e até mesmo a simulação de efeitos naturais como gravidade, atrito, torque, etc.

Mas existe linguagem específica para isso? Não. O C++ é muito utilizado na construção de bibliotecas que auxiliam nesse desenvolvimento, mas há bibliotecas com diversas linguagens. O mesmo vale para Inteligência Artificial, comunicação em redes, simulação de luz e sombras, processamento de imagens (captura a partir de câmera), processamento de som (desde simplesmente "tocar" músicas e efeitos sonoros, até a simular variações de percepção com relação a obstáculos e tipos de materiais obstrutores), e por aí vai.

> Existe alguma pesquisa científica nessa área? Algum projeto em
>   desenvolvimento, ou até mesmo um protótipo?

Se você fala sobre pesquisa científica a respeito da criação de uma *linguagem* específica para jogos, eu acho que não existe. Creio que não há muitas pessoas interessadas em empregar esforços na criação de mais uma linguagem, pelos argumentos colocados até então. O que há, na verdade, é muito esforço para criar linguagens mais *palatáveis* (leia como "fáceis de usar para um público não-especializado"), principalmente para crianças. O [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/) (do MIT), por exemplo, é bem famoso e usa uma abordagem visual. Embora possa ser considerado uma nova "linguagem" (isso é um tanto polêmico), e tenha sido usado em motores/bibliotecas como, por exemplo, o [Stencyl](http://www.stencyl.com/), ele *não é específico para jogos*! Você pode construir qualquer coisa com uma linguagem desse tipo. O Stencyl é bem mais voltado para jogos por ser um ambiente com muitas das necessidades de jogos prontas (detecção de colisão, animação, etc), e por isso está mais para uma biblioteca do que pra uma linguagem.

Tela de um exemplo feito no Scratch:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Do ponto de vista da indústria, o que existe mesmo é uma enorme proliferação de motores de jogos (engines), tal como o Stencyl. A [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d) é uma das mais famosas, mas [a lista é enorme](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_motores_de_jogo).

### Um adendo importante

Tudo o que foi mencionado acima está relacionado à **programação** de jogos. Vale lembrar que a palavra "desenvolvimento" é ampla e genérica demais, e não inclui apenas a programação. O desenvolvimento de jogos inclui também o planejamento de tarefas, a publicidade, venda, etc, e **principalmente**, o Game Design: o processo de concepção do jogo em termos de seus objetivos, condições de término, vitória e derrota, fases, elementos artísticos, elementos mecânicos (regras e como ações se mapeiam em resultados), métodos de interação, experiências emocionais esperadas, etc. Sei que a sua pergunta não envolvia todos esses aspectos, mas há também estudos a respeito de linguagens para a formalização do Game Design.

A formalização do Game Design (necessária não apenas para a documentação e entendimento do "problema", mas também para a comunicação entre membros do time, stakeholders, clientes, etc) é comumente feita de forma livre (com o tal do GDD - o [Game Design Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_design_document)). Porém, há quem trabalhe em formalismos para a descrição de mecânicas, por exemplo.

Por exemplo, um colega na Universidade de São Paulo propôs uma linguagem para a análise e especificação de mecânicas elementares (que ele chamou de "componentes") em jogos. Informações do trabalho dele podem ser encontradas [neste artigo](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-41106-9_3).

Observe, porém, que essa discussão é bem mais polêmica. O processo de Game Design é bastante criativo, e por isso mesmo produzindo um sistema de software, há quem diga que tentativas de formalizar regras só servem para analisar jogos existentes ou fazer variações e combinações destes, mas dificilmente seriam úteis para a construção de novos jogos, com temáticas e mecânicas inovadoras.

Answer (score 13):

Nenhuma séria com os requisitos colocados na pergunta. Até existem umas linguagens de brinquedo que facilitam a criação de jogos, mas só dá para fazer coisas bem toscas. É praticamente pra criança brincar de fazer jogo ([exemplo](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/kodu/)). Se quer fazer jogo sério de alto desempenho usa-se linguagens de propósito geral com bibliotecas específicas para jogos. Nem faz muito sentido ter uma linguagem específica. [Biblioteca faz sentido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines). Ferramenta de apoio faz sentido (muita coisa mais ligada aos ativos do que à programação).

Mesmo se pegar uma linguagem como [BlitzBASIC](http://www.blitzbasic.com/), o que diferencia ela é a biblioteca e não a linguagem.

Existem linguagens que foram adaptadas para facilitar o uso por desenvolvedores de jogos, mas no fundo ainda são linguagens de propósito geral que servem a uma aplicação/jogo específico, não é o que está procurando. Um exemplo é [QuakeC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuakeC). Outra é [UnrealScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_Engine#UnrealScript).

Experimento é possível que exista, mas será mais para provar que pode ser feito e depois praticamente descartado. O mercado não precisa disto. Precisa de melhores bibliotecas.

É improvável que venha existir ou pelo menos ter força no mercado. O que existe está adequado. Não querendo usar PHP para fazer jogos de alto desempenho gráfico já é um bom começo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi. Mas porque você diz que seria descartado? Uma linguagem bem desenvolvida, com uma sintaxe mais amigável que c++ e desempemho otimizado me parece bem aceitável. Pelo menos despertaria interesse em alguns desenvolvedores.

Comment: Está falando de algo específico para jogo, ou só algo melhor que C++?

Comment: Algo específico para jogos. Usei c++ como pivô.

Comment: Aí eu devolvo a pergunta, o que essa linguagem teria de tão bom para fazer as pessoas adotarem ela? Ou seja o que teria a mais que não possa estar em uma biblioteca que faria ela ser tão útil assim para fazer jogos?

Comment: cara, sem pretender desmerecer nenhum trabalho de ninguém, muito menos escolha, muito menos desmerecer alguma linguagem de programação, mas para Jogos, o que vi que mais se aproxima do mundo real é o python

Comment: Ok, você pode ter essa opinião. Eu não vi absolutamente nada que ela ajude especificamente jogos. Ela ajuda em muitas coisas. Ela não tem o desempenho que você está querendo, nem de perto, muito pelo contrário, é uma das linguagens mais lentas que existe. Dá para fazer jogos com Python? Dá. É a linguagem mais adequada? Não! Quase não tem jogos desenvolvidos nela por um bom motivo. O que dá não é fruto da linguagem ou das bibliotecas que vão rodar nela? Das bibliotecas. Se acha isso, deveria justificar porque ela é tão boa para fazer jogos.

Comment: Eu imaginei uma linguagem com poucas regras porém bem definidas, como em Java. Seria em termos de sintaxe e semântica uma mesclagem de C++ e Java. Haveria alocação dinâmica e ela seria compilada. Teria uma performance tão boa quanto uma linguagem de baixo nível ou até mesmo equivalente ao C. Ela teria uma **interface simples** e direta com a GPU (nada complicado como CUDA) para processamento de mídias em geral. Se houvesse alguma coisa assim no mercado eu tenho certeza que muitos adotariam, eu com certeza!

Comment: E quem sabe até um suporte a multiparadigmas, mas isso seria só uma perfumaria em comparação ao objetivo principal.

Comment: E eu quero que um milhão de dólares caia no meu colo. Huumm, não caiu. As coisas não são tão simples assim. Não sei sua idade ou sua experiência, mas todo mundo quer algo tão miraculoso, o duro é fazer .Se os melhores engenheiros do mundo financiados pelas maiores empresas que tem muito interesse não não fizeram dá para desconfiar que não dá para fazer (isso é uma simplificação que cabe em um comentário). Tudo isso junto de uma maneira geral não casa bem, o resto é biblioteca. Note que isso que descreu é o oposto de Python e do objetivo que deseja. Ficaria muito longo explicar cada ponto.

Comment: Vira e mexe aparece uma linguagem nova que diz que vai resolver todos os problemas das outras. Linguagem que vieram para ser tudo o que C++ vieram aos montes. Nenhuma se estabelece. Java fez isso, se estabeleceu, mas de C++ Java não tem nada, Justamente por ser bem diferente e atender uma necessidade em determinado momento é que deu certo. Quem fizer algo ótimo vai se estabelecer. Só que todo mundo acha que vai conseguir fazer quando começa, quando termina fica a mesma coisa de sempre, resolve algum problema que todos aprenderam lidar e causa novos que ninguém quer lidar.

Comment: De qualquer forma nada disso tem a ver com a pergunta, o papo tá bom, linguagem é meu assunto preferido e estudo muito isso, mas são divagações nada relacionados com linguagens específica para jogos, é só sobre uma linguagem qualquer que seja melhor do que as existentes hoje. A intenção do site não é criar debates sobre o que seria bom em uma linguagem. Aqui respondemos perguntas objetivas de tecnologias existentes.

Comment: Eu acredito que o ponto chave foi a pergunta devolvida: "*Aí eu devolvo a pergunta, o que essa linguagem teria [...] a mais que não possa estar em uma biblioteca que faria ela ser tão útil assim para fazer jogos?*" :)